# Resize app designed for Iphone 6 to scale correctly in iphone 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, size-classes

Ok, here is the problem I have designed an application for iphone 6 screen without size classes and autolayout. 
Looking like below in the storyboard. As you can see its simulated size is 4.7 inch.
[image]

It works perfectly when running on iphone 6 devices obviusly.
However when trying to run the app in other devices than iphone 6 it wont scale proportional.

My hope was that if I removed the lanuch screen images only keeping the iphone 6 size it would scale to fit other screens looking the same as if it where run on a iphone 6 only scaled up or down depenging on device.

My launch screen looks like this now

[image]

It does infact scale the app but it scales the app in wrong proportion making it looked chopped like this.

Iphone 5s version of the app looks like this
[image]
As you can see it scales correctly but the aspect gets wrong compared to the iphone 6 version below scaling correctly.
[image]

Here is an ipad version looking like the iphone 5s version scaling wrong.
[image]

It seems to me that the scaling works since I have removed all launch images except the 4.7 display (iphone 6) The problem however seems to be that it scales keeping the aspect of an iphone 5 in width making the iphone 6 display to wide.

I have tried to add launch images for all devices but the problem then is that I need to use autolayout and size classes to make it work.

Is there any way to for instance tell the scaling to keep aspect but use iphone 6 width and height intact without using size classes etc.

To make the question even more simple. Is there any way to scale an app made for strictly iphone 6 so resize to iphone 5s/ipad?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the "trick" with removing the other launch images doesn't work, as you noticed yourself.. This automatic scaling only works from 4" to 4.7" and 5.5" and is only to support older apps on the new devices, not for general purpose "I am too lazy to support all sizes" use cases.. ;-) Apart from that, you should definitely support the native resolutions.

So, to answer your question: You can either just use Auto Layout. This is definitely the preferred approach - after all that's exactly the use case that it has been built for.

Alternatively, if you really don't want to or can't use Auto Layout, you either need to make sure to set your auto resizing masks correctly (e.g. "flexible width" on the stuff that needs to grow/shrink horizontally etc.), or adapt your frames manually in code (which partially defeats the purpose of IB).

Comment: Thanks a lot for a good answer! I guess I thought it where possible to scale any app size but I do realize its only iphone 5 that scales up not the opposite... Anyway I will have to redo with size classes and autolayout to make it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use Auto-Layout or Size Classes, your only hope is to programmatically change the positions/size of each element individually in the `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your `LoginViewController`. You would have to do it also on orientation change (if your app supports it).

It's a lot of work that can be easily be avoided by using Auto-Layout/Size Classes!

Comment: Two comments: 1) For simple stuff, setting the correct auto resizing masks is enough; 2) `viewDidAppear` is not necessarily the best place for layout code, I'd rather consider `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.